# Why implementation of Serializable interface is must in Entity,If an entity instance is passed by value as a detached object

Tags: java, jpa, orm, entity, eclipselink

I'm not clear Why it is must in case of **JPA**.

If an entity instance is passed by value as a detached object, We must required to implement Serializable interface.

Comment: How would the entity be serialized if it doesn't implement Serializable? The same rule applies to all classes: in order to be serialized, an object must be serializable.

Comment: I'm Using my entities without implementing Serializable, Play Framework 2.3x, JPA eclipselink. and working well in Entire project

Comment: So, that means you don't serialize them. If you need to, then you'll need to make them Serializable, as for any other class.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the requirements for Entity classes in [Java EE Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbqa/index.html)  .

Which says:

> If an entity instance is passed by value as a detached object, such as
>   through a session bean’s remote business interface, the class must
>   implement the Serializable interface.

Basically objects should be `Serializable` if you need to transfer them over the wire.

Comment: I too picked the question from docs. and wanted to know the fundamental behind it

Comment: Basically serialization is required to transfer data between JVMs. In case of  passing by value as a detached entities to remote business interfaces, entities may be transfered between JVMs, which requires serialization.
In web applications for caching and optimization purposes, entities may be stored HTTPSessions and session can be serialized.